# Pasar parametro de un dropdownlist a un metodo Jsonresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como están?
Tengo dos consultas
Necesito  enviar un parámetro de la vista  a un método JsonResult y este parámetro necesito capturarlo de un dropdownlist.

La función de la vista es mostrar dos tablas con el mismo parametro, el mismo enviado a dos Store proc diferentes.

Adjunto el codigo de la vista:
El drop esta funcionando  y me lista todos los muelles. Necesito capturarlo.

```
        <div class="col-md-2" style="color: black; justify-content:left;">
            <label for="txtmuelle" class="form-label"> <strong>Muelle</strong></label>
            @Html.DropDownList("datos", items, "Elija una opcion", new { @class = "form-control" , })
        </div>
```

Codigo Controlador:
necesito recibir el idmuelle que se selecciono en la vista en  estos dos metodos.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ListarPendientes(string idmuelle)
    {
        idmuelle = "MS00001";


        List<ControlPendientes> Lista = new List<ControlPendientes>();
        Lista = new CN_ControlPendientes().Listar(idmuelle);

        return Json(new { data = Lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ListarEntregadas(string idmuelle)
    {
        idmuelle = "MS00001";


        List<ControlEntregadas> Lista = new List<ControlEntregadas>();
        Lista = new CN_ControlEntregadas().Listar(idmuelle);

        return Json(new { data = Lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Probe pasar el parametro por un input y no lo recibe tampoco.